# Is it possible to have a non-unique foreign key?

Tags: mysql, relationship

I have a mysql database using phpmyadmin and I'm trying to to make a relationship between two tables called book and catalog. Multiple books can be in one catalog. Here is the columns of my tables:

**Book**
-ISBN (Primary Unique)
-Title
-Author
-Publisher
-catalogID [Foreign Key from catalog table]

**Catalog**
-catalogID [Primary Key Unique]
-genre

As a catalog can have many books I need to mention the catalog more than once that seems to be impossible as the primary key is unique and can't be mentioned twice..

I'm trying for example to add multiple books that have the same foreign key for example book no1 and bookno2 are both in catalog with ID: 1

Any suggestions please?

Comment: PHP does not have foreign keys.  Your database system would have foreign keys.

Comment: So this is an n:1 relationship? You are mentioning the catalogid multiple times, but only in the child table. The referenced table *is*  unique on the catalogid. So no problem. Did I get that right?

Comment: About the _mysql_ vs _sql_ tag: If the user did not mention `phpmyadmin` and `mysql` would it make a difference as to what a possible solution would be?

Comment: can a book be in two catalogs?

Comment: Exactly @usr but when I'm adding another row in the books table and use the same foreign key [catalogID] it will output an error.. Now the foreign key in the book table has an index of 'unqiue' so it's not possible to have two rows with the same foreign key. I made that so I will be able to make a relationship.

Comment: No that's my problem @Félix Gagnon-Grenier because then I would make a many to many relationship

Comment: So why do you have a unique index on something that should not be kept unique? Remove it.

Comment: @usr than I won't be able to make a relationship.. my field needs to have an index for it to be linked to another label. Thats the purpose of my question, I want to make a relationship with a non unique field that has an index.. Excuse my very little knowledge on sql guys but I started learning it this week

Comment: @usr the catalog id *is* unique, in it's table, but present in many rows in the books? does mysql really prevents more then one entry pointing towards a unique id?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier of course not. That would make the feature useless. I guess the OP has switched the two tables in the FK definition.

Comment: use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to illustrate exact table definitions

Comment: @usr not at all! I want this to be clear: A catalog can have many books but a book can only be in one catalog. So the 'many' is at the books table and the 'one' is at the catalog table.

Comment: but hey, before all this @OP, what exactly is not working? creating the foreign key? when you delete an entry? when you say add multiple books, is it with phpMyAdmin, from a php script?

Comment: @Félix Gagnon-Grenier No I'm using MS Visual Studio to add data, I'm creating a connection that handles my queries. Adding one row with a catalogID of 1 for example is working so there is no problems with my relationship. The error is happening when I add another row with catalogID of 1. It's nos possible because I already have a row that have catalogId with value '1' so adding another row with that value would not be possible because the field catalogID is unique.

Comment: Let's say I can have a many to many relationship how would it solve my problem? I would still have unique fields in my junction table so I would't be able to add multiple rows with the same value..

Comment: @Félix Gagnon-Grenier Read again. I said nothing like that I know that unique primary keys are mandatory. What I'm trying to say is if can make a junction table ex.BookCatalog which will have the primary keys booksISBN and catalogID, I did not mention the catalog table. You came up with the same solution..again..and as I told you before I can't make my field non unique because that would remove the index from my field thus removing the possibility of a relationship.

Comment: Solved the problem! For any other readers information. SQL offers a wide variety type of indexes: including 'PRIMARY', 'UNIQUE', 'INDEX', 'FULLTEXT'. I was selecting the index: Unique which made the field that I had impossible to have multiple rows with the same value. I now selected and index called : 'Index' and now it is allowing me to add multiple rows with the same foreign key value. Don't really know what index 'INDEX' mean but if it works why bother? Thanks for all who tried to solve my problem.